# I am trying to add a checked attribute before submitting form and to have the clicked radio sticky using laravel blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am using laravel 8. I managed to get a radio button sticky using the blade template but I can't figure out how to use the checked attribute before submitting and then have the clicked radio button come back checked without it reverting to the default checked.

here's my radio button:

```
<label for="no" class="col form-check-label">No</label>
<input type="radio" checked name="visualCheck" value="no" id="no" class="col p-0 m-0" style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;"  @if(old('visualCheck')=='no') checked @endif />

<label for="yes" class="col form-check-label">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="visualCheck" value="yes" id="yes" class="col" style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;" @if(old('visualCheck')=='yes') checked @endif />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna modify and use this code. But, this is how it can be done.

```
<input type="radio" name="visualCheck" id="no" class="col p-0 m-0" style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;" value="no" {{ old('visualCheck') == "yes" ? 'checked='.'"'.'checked'.'"' : '' }} />
```

You can see this link. [Here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-use-old-function-with-radio-button)

Comment: this also keeps it sticky if I remove the checked attribute (the one outside the blade) but when the form is first loaded I can't have an initial checked radio without it reverting to the initial radio with the checked attribute

Comment: sorry scratch that, made a typo